# Adding class arrays to a List of class arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am trying to create a list of arrays but every time I add a new array in a loop it overrides the values of the other arrays in the list.

```
int p = 5;

for (int j = 1; j < numComputerHands; j++)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 5)
    {
        computerHand[i] = getDeck[p];
        p++;
        i++;
    }

    allComputerHands.Add(computerHand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `Add()`, you're just adding another reference to the same instance of the array. In the end, you have `numComputerHands` number of references to the same array in your List.

You'll need to create a new instance at the start of each iteration.

I'm not sure what type `computerHand` is, so I'll make it an array of `int` below.

```
int p = 5;

for (int j = 1; j < numComputerHands; j++)
{
    computerHand = new int[5];  // change 'int' as needed

    int i = 0;

    while (i < 5)
    {
        computerHand[i] = getDeck[p];
        p++;
        i++;
    }

    allComputerHands.Add(computerHand);
}
```